# Mapbox-gl crashing on android emulator (ionic capacitor)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, mapbox-gl-js, capacitor

I'm working on an app using Ionic 5 Capacitor / Angular, and everything works perfectly until I launch the emulator with mapbox-gl. It just keeps crashing, and I don't get why since it works fine on my web version.

Anyone knows how to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webgl only works on android Q emulator or newer when using a webview to load the app
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37129533

Better test on real devices

Comment: You're a life saver! Mapbox support sucks. Installing the "Android Q" image was the solution.

Comment: What's the best way to test ionic 5 on real devices for ios and android?

Comment: If you have a real device, enable developer options and run the app from Xcode or Android studio. 
Probably best to use live reload so the changes you make are rebuilt and reloaded without re running the app from Xcode/Android studio https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/livereload#capacitor

Comment: This solution worked. Must use android Q Emulator. Thanks!